# why when trying to inport to database more than 500 char i get error?

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i have items in database but why when i am trying to import more than 500 char from a textarea i have error, the datatype of the field is TEXT

here is part of the the form

```
<?php 
//query to get the $ProductDesc and some other codes then
echo "<textarea name='p_desc' id='p_desc' class='input' rows='10' cols='53'>$ProductDesc</textarea>";
?>
```

then the form post in the same page, then i get the value like this:

```
$a4 = $_REQUEST['p_desc'];
```

then i am trying to (update or add) the record,

i have error while importing, and it didn't take effect in updating

and this is my update query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE product SET ProductDesc='$a4' WHERE ProductID = $productID ");
```

please help and thanks in advanced, the error in PHP or what?

the form header:

```
<form name="myform" action="add-product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

am using enctype="multipart/form-data" because i upload images also every thing is good with exception of the textarea

Comment: You forgot the error. And the form.

Comment: Most like likely, character #501 is a single quote.

Comment: [Did you really name your son Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;-- ?"](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: the error is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's new found role as a teacher helps him come to terms with his tumultuous past',' at line 1

but the point is when i edit the product details from PHPMyAdmin it work but the textarea i cannot change it unless its small

Comment: the other fields in the form are working is there a limit in posting data ?? the action of the form is the same page and the method is post, but every thing is working if the characters less than 200 i tested it and its working but i should store a large number of data i am using now 'longtext' but still the same i cannot edit large text but the small text i can

Comment: and I am adding this description to database if it may help:

    ->    Dan Barnes (Steve Austin) is a former pro boxer who retired after growing weary of his violent existence. Now a school janitor, Dan tries to help a new student, Matthew Miller (Daniel Magder), who is being targeted by bullies. While Matthew learns how to box and stand up to his tormentors, one of whom is the school boxing champ (Jaren Brandt Bartlett), Dan's new found role as a teacher helps him come to terms with his tumultuous past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your query add

```
$a4 = mysql_real_escape_string($a4);
```

In fact, you should call this function on any user-specified value going into a query. Not only can you produce errors such as what you have seen, but if were to specify the description as

```
'; DROP TABLE product; --
```

then you'd really be in trouble. This is known as [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) and is something you should be very careful of.

Comment: please could you explain more, please see the form in my question i added now, maybe it the problem?? and please could you explain the SQL injection in simple way

Comment: Nothing wrong with your `form` tag (although specify `enctype` is unnecssary). SQL injection occurs when you include user input in a query without first escaping any special characters, such as quotes and backticks.

When this happens, you open the door for the user to execute arbitrary SQL statements on your server by breaking out of any quotes as in the example I presented above.

If this were properly escaped, then the description I specified would have turned into `\'; DROP TABLE product; -- ` and you would be safe.

Comment: yes thanks alot for your help, i used:
    '$a4 = mysql_real_escape_string($a4);' and it works :) thanks, and am using the enctype because am uploading pictures also.

Answer (score 0):

How do you have your `ProductDesc` field set up? is it `varchar`, `mediumtext`, `longtext`? I always use `longtext` and I have never had any problems with over 500 chars. Post your form, maybe you need to strip some characters out of the Description before it is submitted to the database.

and there was a little hiccup in there :D

instead of

```
<?php 
//query to get the $ProductDesc
<textarea name='p_desc' id='p_desc' class='input' rows='10' cols='53'>$ProductDesc</textarea>
?>
```

use

```
<?php 
//query to get the $ProductDesc
echo "<textarea name='p_desc' id='p_desc' class='input' rows='10' cols='53'>".$ProductDesc."</textarea>";
?>
```

and to fix the update or add function rewrite it so it checks if it is already there or not, then on a if statement add your query or update functions.

And when you hit submit on your form you have now what error does it tell you?!?

Comment: yes it is in echo, the code is running good if the characters in the textarea are less than 200 char. and if it is more i cannot edit it from the admin i should go to PHPMyAdmin to edit it :(